# The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread error while accessing stream data from miracast receiver?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dispatcher, miracast

I have a Miracast receiver Winform application which uses the [Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls) package to access the Windows.Media.Miracast Namespace.

I have used to following code to start the miracast receiver.

```
public MiracastReceiverSession currentSession;
currentSession = castReceiver.CreateSession();
                    currentSession.AllowConnectionTakeover = false;
                    currentSession.MaxSimultaneousConnections = 3;
                    currentSession.ConnectionCreated += OnSessionConnectionCreated;
                    currentSession.MediaSourceCreated += OnSessionMediaSourceCreated;
                    currentSession.Disconnected += OnSessionDisconnect;
MiracastReceiverSessionStartResult startResult = currentSession.Start();
```

Connection is successfully established from both my Windows and Android devices and the screen is shared properly. But when I access the MiracastReceiverVideoStreamSettings in the OnSessionMediaSourceCreated event
I am getting the following error message.

[image: I get the error when the breakpoint is hit]

The error is as follows

System.Exception: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))
at Windows.Media.Miracast.MiracastReceiverStreamControl.GetVideoStreamSettings()
at ImmersiveMiracast.Core.MiracastReceiverWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass59_0.b__0() in D:\Projects\miracast\dev\unify-miracast\ImmersiveMiracast\ImmersiveMiracast\Core\MiracastReceiverWrapper.cs:line 610
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback)
at ImmersiveMiracast.Core.MiracastReceiverWrapper.Invoke(Action a)

I have tried using System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher Invoke(Action) and Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action) but the result is the same.

Comment: Can you quickly [edit] your question and put the errors in Text, as images aren't searchable. Please do this ASAP as people will downvote.

Comment: Oh I *think* I see the problem, in Winform Apps the UI is handled on the Main thread, you can do background tasks but when you want to interact with the UI it has to be via the Main thread. You'll need to provide more code to reproduce the problem if you need help working out what it is, looks like you're going in the right direction `Dispatcher Invoke(Action)` - or read the settings somewhere prior.